# the covariance of the characteristic function of two dependent random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

if *E(X) = E(Y)* = 0 and correlation coefficient is $\rho$, then how do I calculate $E1_{\{X \geq c\}}1_{\{Y \geq c\}}$, where $1_{\{X \geq c\}}$ is the characteristic function.

I tried to calculate it, but it's difficult to link the correlation of *X* and *Y* with the characteristic function.

Comment: Oh, I just worked it out. $E1_{\{X \geq c\}}1_{\{Y \geq c\}} = P(X \geq c, Y \geq c)$. So we need the joint distributribution function

Comment: I think we need more information. For example, are they jointly Normal?

Comment: Yes, we need the joint distribution function of X and Y. The joint distribution can be binormal distribution or something else.